# why does fig,axs=plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True) prevent connection to a Bleakclient.client client.connect on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read temperatures from an ESP32 device and then plot the results after each reading using python with an interactive plot that I draw on the canvas.  Readings are several seconds to several minutes apart.  I am using matplotlib.pyplot for drawing amd Bleakclient for the connection to my device and read the temperature characteristic value.  The program runs on a raspberry pi 4 but it freezes when run in Windows 11 using Visual Studio Code.   I have traced the problem to a fig,axs=plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True) line in the program.  If lined out, the program on Windows 11 returns the temperature values as desired but if line is used the program initiates the plot and returns the client address but then does nothing.  I seems stuck a the client.connect() line.  Program does not provide an exception to the try.  If you close the interactive plot you get a message that something is wrong in python and reporting problem to Microsoft.  A shorten code example to illustrate the problem follows.  I would like to understand problem and how it might be handled.  I left off the actual plotting but that works well on the Pi.

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# address for ESP32C3_MS8670 server 1          
address = "F4:12:FA:0D:XX:XX"
# service uuid="9d574107-bf90-4d24-9bb4-06d6b1XXXXX" and below is the characteristic UUID
UUID_Tc1 = "0e3149af-35f0-49a9-8262-28100cXXXXXX"

async def say_after(adelay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(adelay)
    print(what)

async def get_THP1():
    client = BleakClient(address)
    print(client)
    try:
        await client.connect()
        TempC = await client.read_gatt_char(UUID_Tc1)
        encoding='utf-8'
        tc = TempC.decode(encoding)
        tout=float(tc)
        print("First Sensor")
        print("%.1f degC"%tout)
        await client.disconnect()
        return(tout)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

async def iterations(loops):
    for i in range(loops):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
       
async def main(address):
    iloops=4
    ipause=5
    plt.ion()

    # fig,axs=plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
    async for i in iterations(iloops):
        # get outside readings
        try:
            print(i)
            tout=await get_THP1()
            print(tout)
            
        except Exception as e:
            tout=tout
            print("failed -using previous values")
            print(e)
        ipstr="waited %i seconds "% (ipause)
        await say_after(ipause,ipstr)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(address))
```

I expected the program to do several loops of reading temperatures.  In the example above it should read the BLE characteristic temperature value about every 5 seconds for 3 repeated readings.

Comment: You could try to [report a bug](https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/contributing.html#submitting-a-bug-report) for matplotlib

Comment: Have you tried running your code outside of vscode?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  I also thought might be a setting in VSCode but tried Anaconda Spyder, PyCharm Community, and Visual Studio Community 2022 to run python and all gave me the same freeze.   I did contact Microsoft support about the issue and they suggested I go to a community forum for help.  It was easier to post query here than on the Microsoft Community Forum and I use this source for troubleshooting more than I wish I needed to....  The code runs as designed on my raspberry pi 4 so don't think matplotlib issue.

Comment: Please also try to run python without any IDE such as Visual Studio etc. just in case it has something to do with the interactive terminal they generally use

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a method to acquire data and then plot it in the same module while running windows.  I could do it on a raspberry pi4.  After some suggestions from Henrik Bildh, a bleak developer, I decided to try to use a multiprocessing approach suggested elsewhere on this forum. I moved the plotting code to another module and then used a pipe connection to move a data string of the current readings to a def in the module. I ran the second module as a child process while I was acquiring data. Unlike the initial plotting attempts in the async module in the second module I could plot data interactively.

These are the key lines of code that were based on a multiprocessing example in Stack Overflow.

Parent:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Pipe
# pipe declaration and start ahead of acquisition loop
        parent_conn,child_conn = Pipe()
        p = Process(target=dread, args=(child_conn,))
        p.start()
# this code is inside of the acquisition loop, sends new data
        xtime=mdates.date2num(dtime)
        strdata=(f"{xtime},{tout:6.1f},{tin:6.1f},{hout:6.1f},{hin:6.1f},{pout:9.2f},{pin:9.2f}")
        parent_conn.send(strdata)  # send data as string msg
```

child:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Pipe

#dread is the main child process  
def dread(child_conn):
      data=[19518.506628694817, 28.5, 25.9, 34.9, 0.0, 1013.1, 1013.1]        #just some data to set array size ]
      rtext=child_conn.recv()    # receive data here
      values = [float(i) for i in rtext.split(',')]
      newrow=np.array([values])
      data=np.vstack([data, newrow]) # adds the new row of data to previous
      update() # just links the data arrary to plot variables and calls the plot function
      plt.show()
      child_conn.close()
```